# Deleted root user. Unable to login to mysql

Tags: mysql

I have deleted the root@localhost user and logged out of mysql.
Now i am unable to login.

What is the way to login and create the user back?

Comment: are you working on localhost? or shared hosting or dedicated hosting?

Comment: localhost. Just practicing something.

Comment: ok... you are using WAMP/Xampp on windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu. I was trying to connect APACHE SQOOP with mysql. So i tried to give privilege to root@localhost by deleting it and recreating it. But after deleting root i inadvertently logged out.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu you need follow below steps

Stop mysqld and restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option.

```
> service mysqld stop
> service mysqld start --skip-grant-tables
```

Connect to the mysqld server with just: mysql (i.e. no -p option, and username may not be required).

```
> mysql
```

Issue the following commands in the mysql client:

```
> UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that, you should be able to run GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'; and have it work.

```
> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

After that stop mysqld service and start again as normal with no options.

Comment: In this scenario user "root" still exists. That is not OP scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the server with the --skip-grant-tables option, as Haresh Vidja says. This way, it would skip authentication, you will be able to access the mysql console without user and password.

If you read this option, it says **SKIP GRANT TABLES**, and therefore, the GRANT statement will not work, and neither CREATE USER.

So, you will have to insert the root user manually, setting values for its fields.

The statement you must use will be similar to:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user  SET user = 'root',  host = 'localhost',   password = Password('your_password'),   ssl_type ='',   ssl_cipher='',   x509_issuer = '',   x509_subject='',   authentication_string = '',    Select_priv = 'y',     Insert_priv = 'y',     Update_priv = 'y',     Delete_priv = 'y',     Create_priv = 'y',     Drop_priv = 'y',     Reload_priv = 'y',     Shutdown_priv = 'y',     Process_priv = 'y',     File_priv = 'y',     Grant_priv = 'y',     References_priv = 'y',     Index_priv = 'y',     Alter_priv = 'y',     Show_db_priv = 'y',     Super_priv = 'y',     Create_tmp_table_priv = 'y',     Lock_tables_priv = 'y',     Execute_priv = 'y',     Repl_slave_priv = 'y',     Repl_client_priv = 'y',     Create_view_priv = 'y',     Show_view_priv = 'y',     Create_routine_priv = 'y',     Alter_routine_priv = 'y',     Create_user_priv = 'y',     Event_priv = 'y',     Trigger_priv = 'y',   Create_tablespace_priv = 'y';
```

Notice you will have to replace 'your_password' with the password you want to use.

After this, you should restart the server without the option to skip grant tables, and log in as root with your new password.

The user table has many columns, if in doubt, you can fetch with

```
DESC user;
```

Reference: https://www.cloudtechtiq.com/blog/restoring-deleted-root-user-and-password-mysql